# How to capture an app screen shot on Xbox

Tags: xbox, xbox-one

I'm using Xbox one s. In games, I can capture a screen shot easily. But now I want to capture a screen shot in app.

Is there any way?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically capture your own app, or just some random app?

Comment: Random, maybe when watching youtube or netflix, take a screen shot.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn, do you have ideas on doing it programmatically?

Comment: You can take a screenshot of your OWN application's RenderTarget easily with a solution like [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ScreenGrab). By design a UWP does *not* have access to other app's render targets.